# Is it possible for built in webcam and built in microphone to be turned on when laptop is shut down?

Tags: privacy

If a hacker wants to stalk someone via laptop when they are least expecting it , Could the hacker activate the built in microphone and built in camera (if the screen is up) when the laptop is shut down or out of charge?

Thank you,

Answer (score 3):

No.

If the laptop is shutdown or out of charge, all ports, connections, services, applications, daemons, etc. on the computer are no longer functional. Webcam and microphone, like any other hardware component, have dependencies on such services to be functional.

Having said that, if a hacker is able to make it seem to the user like the computer is shut down while it is quietly still in operation, theoretically it is possible to use the microphone to record sound and webcam to record video.